# Encrypted Mac in rajant?

Tags: java, variables

I am interrogating a Rajant equipment to get its mac, but when capturing the data it gives me the following way

```
\ 204 \ 215 \ 204 \ 376 \ 021 \ 353 (real mac e48d8cf21c0e)
```

what type of encryption does it have?

Comment: As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: The 3-digit numbers look like octal but don't map to the mac address in an obvious way.